# How to calculate geometric functions of tikz coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I have two points in tikz (`m1` and `m4`) and would like to calculate the angle of the line defined by these two points and the horizontal line.

The math would be `atan( (x2-x1) / (y2-y2) )`, and I tried doing this implementation (storing the result in the variable `\start`.

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\start}{atan((\pgfextracty{m4}-\pgfextracty{m1})/(\pgfextractx{m4}-\pgfextractx{m1}))}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile and throws this error:

```
! You can't use a prefix with `the character ='.
<to be read again> 
=
l.41 ...y{m1})/(\pgfextractx{m4}-\pgfextractx{m1}))}
```

**I am interested in how to make more complex calculations with tikz coordinates than addition, multiplication.** The above is just an illustration. Here's a small mwe, that takes two coordinates makes a small calculation and prints the result to a node, as a slightly l'art pour l'art example.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}
\begin{document} 
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (m1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (m4) at ($(m1) +(170:70)$);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\start}{atan((\pgfextracty{m4}-\pgfextracty{m1})/(\pgfextractx{m4}-\pgfextractx{m1}))}

\node at (1,1) {\start};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to help you, it would be good to know what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your purpose is to calculate the angle between a line defined by two points `(m1)--(m4)` and the horizontal axis, then you have two options according to your needs. First, you can use pgf math engine with the command `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` used for this purpose. Second option is to use the `tkz-euclide` package (internally loads tikz), but then you need three points. See the example below for explanation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} % Important
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate(m1)at(0,0);
\coordinate(m4)at(5,2);
\coordinate(m0)at([xshift=5cm]m1);    
\draw (m0)--(m1)--(m4);

% first method
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{m1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{m4}{center}}
\edef\twomangle{\pgfmathresult}    
\node  at (0,-2){\twomangle};

% Second method
\tkzFindAngle(m0,m1,m4)
\tkzGetAngle{angleBCA};    
\node at (0,-3){\angleBCA};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the first method, you should use `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` twice : to get the angle between `m0` and `m4` and to remove the angle between `m0` and `m1`...